Is Nirvana the Source of all life?
I read the following in the internet:

The Source of all life is Nirvana.

Is this true?
I also read the following on the internet:

Life involves suffering, dissatisfaction, and impermanence. This
suffering is inherent in birth, aging, illness, and death.

If Nirvana is the Source of Life, is Nirvana the Source of Suffering?

Internet is not a good source of knowledge. Many people spread ignorance to keep fueling their cravings!!
Nibbana can not be the source of life. Life is originated , born , created while Nibbana is unoriginated, unborn , uncreated and unbecoming. Nibbana is the end of suffering. Life has inevitable suffering because Sabbe Sankhara Anicca, all conditioned phenomena are impermanent. That which is impermanent is suffering. That which is suffering can not be called Self.

"Internet is not a good source of knowledge. Many people spread ignorance to keep fueling their cravings!!" - of course. Language is inherently dualistic and limited and cannot explain it properly. Silence is the best. It is the best teacher. It's not a "word". At best words can point to truth, but they not the truth. When we stop thinking then there is peace and refreshment.

@BrendanDarrer You don’t need words to escape from suffering. Silence or no thought is not the answer. Be mindful day and night. Purpose is not peace or refreshment but Nibbana.

@Remyla I have been taught that everyone has Buddha-nature; one has "only" to remove obscurations to bring it forth. Is this the same thing?

To me peace and Nibbana is one and the same. The purpose is peace! Peace / quietude means no suffering.

"You don’t need words to escape from suffering." What do you mean by this? It doesn't make any sense. Sounds like rubbish/gibberish. Truth is simple and clear and helpful - You're statement sounds like you're trying to mess with my mind. That's what it feels like to me. The sage tries to help people, he or she does not try to mess with them. I think you need to explain more clearly what you mean by Nibbana? Life is not suffering (obviously it can be sometimes; without life you wouldn't exist...

...Life as in spirit or soul or Ātman, or tree of life), life is a good. Buddha says "all love life, all fear death." Remember the truth often sounds paradoxical! (Tao te ching).

...paradox means two contradictory things can both be true, even though they contradict each other.

Buddha also says life is suffering. Of course it is, but it can also be wonderful, joyful and peaceful and the source of our existence. Life can be many things.

@BrendanDarrer You have not understood the gravity of the situation. Anything less than complete extinguishment (Nibbana) has dire consequences. I will explain a little about words. Once you have touched fire and felt burnt then from next time onwards you don’t need words to recognise that Fire should not be touched with bare hands. You have too many doubts . Post a separate question and I will answer.

I think the answer might be "yes, to the extent that monism is a thing":
There are various expressions of monism

"The Tao is the source of all things"
"God is the creator of heaven and earth"
etc.

This "one" may be nameless -- and/or have many names -- and to the extent that it is indeed "One", and everything, then how could it not be nibbana?
It may be a doctrine or view inherent in later forms of Buddhism -- e.g. "buddha-nature", "original face", "not form", ...
It might be pre-Buddhist too, e.g. the Wikipedia article linked above says that,

Monism has been discussed thoroughly in Indian philosophy and Vedanta throughout their history starting as early as the Rig Veda.

If that's someone's view I don't see the point in disputing it.
IMO "nibbana" has a limited meaning in the suttas, i.e. as an end-state or goal associated with complete/permanent uprooting of "defilements" and "effluents" -- having said that, an answer like this one associates that with "views that incorporate dualities, i.e. subject and object" -- and so the topic returns again to "monism".

I always imagined nibbana to be the default and all phenomena springs from this. To an extent as I could try explain. (not creationism)
The root issue of samsara is the 3 root poisons, more importantly the root delusion/ignorance of self which the other 2 poisons arise from. This root delusion itself is a defilement, a klesha if you will, THE root defilement. Then that begs the question "what is life/existence without this defilement of ignorance/delusion" and the answer is only nibbana.
So in a more generic but crude example to explain my understanding, I visualise "being" as a white ball of light in the darkness and the root delusion of clinging to self being a black layer of tar covered around this white ball of light, dimming it but not extinguishing it. Then in turn more layers of black tar over that signifying the "lesser" defilements. Which if you can understand the analogy/visualisation, removing defilements makes this white light less dim and more defilements make it more dim. In turn removing defilements allows us to "see clearly" the white light/nibbana. Completely eradicating the black tar allows this white light to shine forth as intended/defualt but also removing this black tar does not eradicate the white light itself as the white light does not need anything to shine, it only needs black tar to shine dimly.
Very crude example but seeing nibanna is inexplicable as too our own experience of it, all we can use to elaborate it to each other are very basic sensory experience analogies. Despite it being non-dependant on such "trivial" things.
So essentially, as default, beings are already in nibbana, it is just we are defiled by the root delusion (and subsequent defilements that arise in dependence of this delusion) that we instead experience what is essentially the dream like reality of samsara.
As for suffering, Buddha explained this as the 2nd noble truth. Attachment is what causes suffering. Also being one of the 12 dependant related links that forces us to arise again in samsara. (so too is ignorance, the root delusion)

the suttas say the self delusion arises from craving (i..e., from love & hate). rather than craving, lust & hate arise from the self

SN 22.81 = assumes form to be the self. That assumption is a fabrication. Now what is the cause, what is the origination, what is the birth, what is the coming-into-existence of that fabrication? To an uninstructed, run-of-the-mill person, touched by that which is felt born of contact with ignorance, craving arises. That fabrication is born of that. And that fabrication is inconstant, fabricated, dependently co-arisen

the suttas say "a being" is merely attachment & a view (SN 23.2; SN 5.10)

The 12 dependant related links explain the process of coming into being. You are right that grasping is essentially what creates the delusion (attachments cause the ignorance) and from that lead to becoming, birth, aging and death. Removing attachments in turn release us from the ignorance that creates form. though there are multiple entry points in the 12 links one can look to as the "beginning" of the process. The way Buddha explained it is that ignorance/delusion is the root cause. i.e the 1st of the 12 links. This is the ultimate objective, to remove this delusion and once removed, one...

may still have to go through the rest of the process of aging and death but the removal of the ignorance removes attachements which in turn remove becoming which removes the process of being recreated (into form). Nibbana

aging & death are grasping. Refer to the end if MN 130 and SN 12.66. The Dhamma is defined as something seen & verified.
